# PCoA scatter plot-individual symbols for populations in package adegenet

Tags: r

I am new to R, and am running PCoAs using the package Adegenet.  I would like each of my populations to be given a different symbol, and have but unsuccessful at doing so (I can assign different colors to each population, but not symbols). I've tried the following:

```
X<-scaleGen(data, scale=FALSE, miss="mean")
pcoX<-dudi.pco(dist(X), scannf=FALSE, nf=3)
col<-palette(c("black", "gray27", "gray45", "gray71"))
s.class(pcoX$li, pop(data), col=col,xax=1, yax=3, axesell=FALSE, grid=FALSE, 
+         cstar=0, pch=(c(16:19)))
```

but rather than each population being given a different symbol, each symbol seems randomly distributed among my four populations. 
Any suggestions to fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what your data looks like? Maybe do head(pcoX)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
X<-scaleGen(data, scale=FALSE, miss="mean")
pcoX<-dudi.pco(dist(X), scannf=FALSE, nf=3)

col<-palette(c("black", "gray27", "gray45", "gray71"))

temp <- as.integer(pop(data))
mypch <- c(16:19)[temp]

s.class(pcoX$li, pop(data), col=col,xax=1, yax=3, axesell=FALSE, grid=FALSE, 
+         cstar=0, pch=mypch)
```

Comment: Please explain your answer